# Visual Studio 2010 ReportViewer Assembly References

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I didn't do C# for quite some time, but I'm updating some of my projects now. I imported a project from Visual Studio 2008 into 2010.
Building got me some confusing errors into the log:

```
      Considered "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll", but it didn't exist.
              Considered "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.exe", but it didn't exist.
[...]
 For SearchPath "{GAC}".
```

I don't really know which assembly reference this refers to and how I can add it... From what I think to know this is a standard assembly reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download from here: [Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=A941C6B2-64DD-4D03-9CA7-4017A0D164FD)

[After installation, I believe this DLL is loaded into the GAC.]

Bill McCarthy's post [Upgrading Report applications to 4.0](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bill/archive/2010/04/19/upgrading-report-applications-to-4-0.aspx) might be useful.