# Install .Net assembly reference in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I an [earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870403/visual-studio-2010-reportviewer-assembly-references) I got some help to track down a deprecated .Net assembly reference and I was successfully able to port my project to build within Visual Studio 2010.

Is there any option to get this ReportViewer to work within Mono? Building the project with MonoDevelp 2.2.2 currently gives me similar errors:

```
Assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common Version=8.0.0 [...] not found
Assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms [...] not found
```

Thanks for all help :)

Comment: Well, you would need to find a Mono port. Given the first part of that name, not likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running all of the dependent assemblies through the [Mono Migration Analyser](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA). It currently targets Mono 2.6, but 2.8 has recently been released.

If the assemblies pass the tests in that then they'll work fine in Mono. If they don't pass the tests then there's a slim chance that they'll work, it just depends which functionality is used.